# how I can share physical folders or files (other than link on mail) between these two subdomains?

Tags: azure

In my project, there is facility to share word file from one user to another user registered on different tenants. My tenants are based on different subdomains of particular organisation. For ex. I am sharing word file from 'abc.onmicrosoft.com' to 'xyz.onmicrosoft.com'. abc and xyz are the child companies/departments of main company. Both email ids are registered on different tenants. My query is how I can share physical folders or files (other than link on mail) between these two subdomains? Is there any setting regarding it on microsoft azure?

Comment: Check federation - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-single-adfs-multitenant-federation

Comment: `how I can share physical folders or files (other than link on mail)` Can you specify how exactly you want to share files?